# How to search for locations using Tags inside OpenStreetMap

Tags: google-places-api, openstreetmap

Using the [Nominatim](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/search.html?) APIs, am able to do a search based on a query. However, all the results returned have a Tag associated with them, like `leisure=fitness_centre`.

How can I, thus, use the OpenStreetMap APIs to search a given location (say London) for all the `fitness_centre` tags? Idea is to be able to search the map, zero in a location (say London, Oxford etc.) and then search for all places/locations with Tag [`leisure=fitness_centre`]

Using Google Places API, one can search using tags using something like below (specifying `type=gym`) -

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=51.509865,-0.118092&radius=50000&sensor=true&key=&types=gym

Only issue with the Google Places API is that they are extremely pricey!!, so looking for OpenStreetMap as an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For searching specific objects in OSM, Overpass API is usually a good choice.

There is a nice frontend available called overpass turbo. Open the wizard, enter "leisure=fitness_centre in London" and it will generate an appropriate query:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
{{geocodeArea:London}}->.searchArea;
(
  node["leisure"="fitness_centre"](area.searchArea);
  way["leisure"="fitness_centre"](area.searchArea);
  relation["leisure"="fitness_centre"](area.searchArea);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Then hit run to see the results on the map: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1fbg

Please note that the `{{geocodeArea:London}}->.searchArea;` part is a feature added by the overpass turbo frontend. Overpass API won't understand this geocoding request. Instead, you have to replace it with an area query and the corresponding relation ID (in this case `area(id:3600065606)->.searchArea;`).

Another thing to note is that Overpass API servers shouldn't be used for heavy queries or commercial purposes. If you need this kind of service then install your own Overpass API instance or use a commercial Overpass API provider.